# vector doesn't work in struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct, addition

I have struct like this:

```
struct element{
char ulica[10];
vector<int> dane[3];
int wolne;
int w;
element *lewy, *prawy, *ojciec;
};
```

And I'm implementing kind of AVL tree. When key's are the same i need to put some int values to dane (dane[0], dane[1], dane[2] describe 3 different value) so I use

```
tmp2->dane[0].push_back(number)
```

EDIT. Here is code where I'm adding a values to this vector, it's half of the function because secod half is about rotations in AVL.

```
void wstaw_wezel(){

    element *tmp2; //tmp2 bedzie ojcem nowo wstawionego elementu
    tmp2=korzen;
    while(tmp2!=NULL){
    if(strcmp(tmp2->ulica, tmp->ulica)<0){
        if(tmp2->prawy!=NULL){
            tmp2=tmp2->prawy;
        }
        else{
            tmp->ojciec=tmp2;
            tmp2->prawy=tmp;
            cout<<"Wstawiam pod prawy "<<tmp2->ulica<<endl;
            if(tmp2->w!=0) tmp2->w=0;
            else tmp2->w=-1;
            break;
        }
    }
    else if(strcmp(tmp2->ulica, tmp->ulica)>0){
        if(tmp2->lewy!=NULL){
            tmp2=tmp2->lewy;
        }
        else{

            tmp->ojciec=tmp2;
            tmp2->lewy=tmp;
            if(tmp2->w!=0) tmp2->w=0;
            else tmp2->w=1;
            cout<<"Wstawiam pod lewy "<<tmp2->ulica<<endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    else{
        cout<<"2 bloki na tej samej ulicy"<<endl;
        for(int i=0; i<tmp2->dane[0].size(); i++) cout<<tmp2->ulica<<" "<<tmp2->dane[0][i]<<endl;
        tmp2->numery.push_back(tmp->numery[0]);
        tmp2->dane[0].push_back(tmp->dane[0][0]);
        for(int i=0; i<tmp2->dane[0].size(); i++) cout<<tmp2->ulica<<" "<<tmp2->dane[0][i]<<endl;
        tmp2->dane[1].push_back(tmp->dane[1][0]);
        tmp2->dane[2].push_back(tmp->dane[2][0]);
        tmp2->wolne+=tmp->dane[2][0];
        break;

    }
    }
    if(tmp->ojciec==NULL){
         korzen=tmp;
         return;
    }
```

where tmp2 is a pointer to this struct (I checked adrres where it points and every time it's the same adrres).

Where is problem? If I add new value to vector it is until the loop where i do it ends. Finally instead having fe. 4 values in vector i have one, the last added value. Vector don't add new value to the end, just replacing it.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a *little bit* vague. What's the error?

Comment: Do You really need an array of vectors? Post a minimal code sample depicting the problem.

Comment: Please post the loop that you mentioned.

Comment: you probably want something like vector<int> dane; and so something like tmp2->dane.push_back(number)

Comment: Loop added. I need and array of vectors, not a vector of total size 3.

Comment: @lisek: I updated my answer below.  See if that works for you.

Comment: Looks like your 'for' loops are missing an entry

Answer (score 2):

You declare the initial size of a std::vector in its constructor, so one way you can accomplish this is:

```
struct element
{
    char ulica[10];
    std::vector<int> dane;
    int wolne;
    int w;
    element *lewy, *prawy, *ojciec;

    element() : dane(3) {}
};
```

If you don't include the constructor, the initial size of the vector will be 0.  In any event, to add an element to the back, just use `tmp2->dane.push_back(number);`  This will add the value in `number` to the back of the vector `tmp2->dane` which may result in a change in the amount of allocated memory for the vector instance.

**UPDATE**:  Based on the comment from the OP that he needs three vectors try this:

```
struct element
{
    char ulica[10];
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > dane;
    int wolne;
    int w;
    element *lewy, *prawy, *ojciec;

    element() : dane(3) {}
};
```

To add elements to the vectors, simply use `tmp2->dane[i].push_back(number)` where `i` is the index of the vector to use, and `number` is the new number to add to the `i`<sup>th</sup> vector, which is the same convention you seem to be using in your code segment above.

**Update 2**:  Based on additional information below, I think a redesign of your data structure is called for.  You're mixing the meaning of the various components and by more clearly delineating the functions of the data element and the AVL data structure management, you will be able to more clearly distinguish between the two.  So try this instead.  Have a data structure specifically for the "value" portion of your tree nodes, as in:

```
struct house
{
    int house_number;
    int unique_value0;
    int unique_value1;

    house(int hn, int uv0, int uv2)
        : house_number(hn),
          unique_value0(uv0),
          unique_value1(uv1) {}
};

template <typename VALUE> struct node
{
    std::string key;
    std::vector<VALUE> values;
    int left, right;
    node<VALUE> *leftNode, *rightNode, *parentNode;
};
```

From here, you create a root node:

```
node<house> *root;
```

When you want to add a house to a street, `node<house> *s`, all you need to do is

`s->values.push_back(house(a, b, c));`

Of course a better alternative is to use what C++ already has for this.  That is, there is a structure in the standard library called [std::multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/multimap/) which does pretty much what you're trying to do.  In this case, you can simple declare

```
std::multimap<std::string, house> myMap;
```

This probably won't use AVL balancing.  It more likely will be a Red-Black Tree, but it's all done for you.

Comment: Nothing changed. For this value: 'a 1' 'a 2' 'a 3' 'a 4', a is a key and number is int added by push_back it prints: a 1, a 1 a 2, a 2 a 3, a 3 a 4 and in main before programs ends just print a 4.

Comment: Then it would seem the problem isn't with the vector, but in some of the logic as to how you're using the vector.  So, it would be useful to see another edit to your question which describes more clearly the output you expect and how it differs from the output you see.

Comment: I can send a whole code, but it's about 500 lines + one txt file. But what about logic? I make a vector, use 4-5 times push_back and then print whole vector.

Comment: So, I'm not clear on what you expect to see from your results.  You say there's a problem, but you need to clearly state what your expectations for the program are, and how it's actual behavior differs from your expectations.  In an earlier comment, you provided some input and some output.  That's part of what I'm looking for.  The other part should be a description of how that output differs from your expectations.  What should the output have been for that input?  Were you just expecting the output to be the same as the input?

Comment: @lisek:  One other thing.  I really don't see in your code what you're trying to accomplish with three vectors.  When you have multiple values for a given key, why can't you just store duplicates into a single vector (which you can sort if you'd like)?  In fact it would vastly simplify your code if you just stored all of the values for a particular key in the vector, and not distinguish when there are multiple values for a single key.  Always assume there will be multiple values.

Comment: I will try make it more clear. I'm build a AVL try to store a streets names as a key. I'm looking for street and if I don't find it, add it to tree, but if I find it, I want to add house number to vector, so I can reach to each house on this street just find one key in a tree. I need 3 vectors because one house have his own street, number and two other unique values. I must have a function to find a house so if I found a street, i can look throught vector for looking his number, then I have vector iterator and I can get 2 others value.

Comment: @lisek:  I found it difficult to follow the logic of your program, and I'm still not convinced you've got the right approach as described in your comment.  I have posted a couple of possible redesign tips which should make it easier to figure out where the problem is by clearly delineating between the content you are trying to manage and  the data structure you're using to do the management.  When you try to do too many things all at once, the logic becomes difficult to manage and it's highly error prone.  It's better to split up the pieces and develop and test them independently.

Comment: I will try this mothode, but I don't know how to print fe. each house_numbers. pointer->values[iterator] and what now?

Comment: My code posted as a question works good, but I had wrong if so it's "crash" whole idea. Thanks by the way.

Comment: No problem.  Good luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 0):

How do you alloc the struct element?, it seems that the `vector<int> dane[3];` has been initialized successful,  but its inner vector does not been initialised.

try to add a ctor method to the `struct element`?

```
struct element 
{
    char ulica[10];
    vector<int> dane[3];
    int wolne;
    int w;
    element *lewy, *prawy, *ojciec;

    element()
    {
        dane[0] = vector<int>();
        dane[1] = vector<int>();
        dane[2] = vector<int>();
    }
};
```